# Como mostrar un marcador en Google Maps a partir de la latitud y la longitud que estan en una base de datos con PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un CRUD en PHP, en el archivo create.php, tengo dos campos de latitud y longitud, esos campos se guardan bien en la base de datos, ambos campos son del tipo FLOAT(10,6).

Ahora, en la vista principal, tengo un mapa de Google Maps, en donde quiero que la dirección mostrada sea la de esa latitud y longitud, mi código para mostrar el mapa es el siguiente,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = { lat: $latitud, lng: $longitud};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: uluru
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            title: 'Guía Nacional Py'
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

    }
</script>
```

El mapa se muestra perfectamente, pero no con la latitud y la longitud guardada en la base de datos, en la parte de: var uluru = { lat: $latitud, lng: $longitud}; es donde defino esos valores, como podria hacer para que eso funciones?

El código PHP con el que estiro todos los datos desde la base de datos (Mysql), es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
require("so-admin/config.php");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$n = null;
if (!empty($_GET['n'])) {
    $n = $_REQUEST['n'];
    if(is_numeric($n)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM anuncios where id = ?";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($n));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $imagen = $data['imagen'];
        $nombre = $data['nombre'];
        $direccion = $data['direccion'];
        $correo = $data['correo'];
        $video = $data['video'];
        $latitud = $data['latitud'];
        $longitud = $data['longitud'];
        $telefono = $data['telefono'];
        $celular = $data['celular'];
        $web = $data['web'];
        $facebook = $data['facebook'];
        $ciudad = $data['ciudad'];
        $categoria = $data['categoria'];
        $descripcion = $data['descripcion'];
        $url = "http://www.guianacionalpy.com/administrador/anuncio.php?n=" . $data['id'];;
    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

if (null == $n ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

?>

Los demás datos si se muestran de manera perfecta, solo el mapa es lo que esta fallando.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donde declaras estas variables: $latitud y $longitud en javascript ?.

Si estas variables las tienes en PHP y estan en el mismo archivo donde declaras el Google Maps:

Tendrias que escribir algo así:

```
 var uluru = { lat: <?= $latitud ?>, lng: <?= $longitud ?>};
```

Comment: Pefecto, funciono! gracias.